# python can't find module 'python-for-android'

Tags: python, android, python-for-android

I am trying to compile my python program into an android APK file. I installed the package 'python-for-android'. when i tried to use it, i go an error saying `C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: No module named python-for-android`. Can someone please tell me what is going wrong?

https://pypi.org/project/python-for-android/

Comment: is there some alternative  module name i should use in the command

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is being installed into a different location than where you pip installed the library. If you can give more details about how you installed the package, it might help identify the issue.

Is it possible that you have two python versions, and it installed it into the wrong version.

Using virtual environments might make it easier to understand what is going on. If you pip install into a virtual environment, you can be pretty confident that it is installing into the correct version of python.

Comment: Thanks. I will see to it